# Is it possible to view all questions with My Tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

I know I can click on unanswered questions and choose the "My Tags" tab, but there is no way to sort that view (e.g. by date, votes, etc.), and I'd also really like to be able to see all questions that are related to my tags, not just unanswered ones. Is this possible? If not, then please consider this a feature request.

Thanks,

--jed

Comment: Probably a good one to post over at meta.so, that's a SE design thing and they deal with those questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do something with a [custom tag filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/popular) which will allow you to view questions for specified tags on one or more stackexchange sites.